# Postorder Бинарное Дерево java

Tags: java

с толкнулся с такой проблемой, создал бинарное дерево и надо вывести значение в порядке postorder, данный код который у меня

```
public void IzvadePostorder() {
    if (root == null)
        return;
    Stack<Node> s = new Stack<Node>();
    s.push(root);
    while (s.empty() == false) {
        Node mynode = s.peek();
        System.out.print(mynode.data + " ");
        s.pop();

        if (mynode.left != null) {
            s.push(mynode.left);
        }
        if(mynode.right != null) {
            s.push(mynode.right);
        }




    }
}
```

Данный код выводит 40 78 25 32 10 
Код должен выводить 10 32 25 78 40
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить

Comment: Можно двумя стэками https://ideone.com/HqlzkU

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста. Там можно одним стэком сделать, но что-то не охота заморачиваться. Реализацию можно найти и разобраться.